# Activity overlaying. WindowManager.LayoutParams

Tags: java, android

I'm developing lock screen. And I need my lock screen activity be over all apps. 
So, I have this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View oView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lock_screen, null); // lock_screen is .xml file
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(oView, params);
```

It works, but not at all. Everything is frozen, the navigation baris working, but touch screen is not. **How can I make only my activity be over everything and can't quit it?**

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've only overlaid a view, not the activity.